# Reversing an animation with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, less, css-animations

I'm applying a mixin to rotate something by adding the class via jQuery:

```
.rotate-45-left() {
    -webkit-animation: rotate45left 2.55s ease;
    -moz-animation: rotate45left 2.55s ease;
    animation: rotate45left 2.55s ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes rotate45left {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
```

This works the first time, however I'd like to then animate the transition *back* to its default, unrotated position.  I've tried adding an additional class but this overrides the original animation; removing the class resets it without animating.  Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Use transition instead of animation?

Comment: @seven-phases-max transitions are enabled however the rotation doesn't animate.

Comment: 50% with -45 deg and at 100% back to normal. 
 `50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);}`

Comment: @yogendarji mind demonstrating this (I'm not sure how to target `50%` with a class)?  I'll select as an answer if it works :)

Comment: Transition [example](https://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/NgJZyV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function back(){
document.getElementById('ele').classList = "rotate-0-left";
}
```

```css
.rotate-45-left {
    -webkit-animation: rotate45left 1.55s ease;
    -moz-animation: rotate45left 1.55s ease;
    animation: rotate45left 1.55s ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.rotate-0-left {
    -webkit-animation: rotate0left 1.55s ease;
    -moz-animation: rotate0left 1.55s ease;
    animation: rotate0left 1.55s ease;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotate45left {
    
    100%{
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
}


@keyframes rotate0left {
   0%{
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
   }
    100%{
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="ele" class="rotate-45-left"> Rotate </h1>

<input type="button" value="back to original" onClick="back()"/>
```

Comment: How would you trigger to 50% on command, and then to 100% on command?

Comment: @SB2055 Did you mean after applying "rotate-45-left" class, element will rotate 45 degree and then it will reset to it's original position with same animation? correct?

Comment: Yes.  Rotate to 45, wait for the user to do something, then rotate back to original position (0).